# How to add method description in Swagger UI in PyCharm with Flask-RESTX

Tags: python, pycharm, swagger-ui, flask-restx

I am using Swagger as my API tooling framework and I just found this page: https://petstore.swagger.io/ and saw how each method has a description.

For example: `POST: pet/` is described by `add a new Pet to the store`.

I thought adding this kind of description in PyCharm, using Flask-RESTX. How can I do this? I read the specification page of RESTX, but I didn't find any useful help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-swagger provides a method (swagger) that inspects the Flask app for endpoints that contain YAML docstrings with Swagger 2.0 Operation objects.

So this is a way to add description and summary.

```
class Data(Resource):
   @api.doc(description="getSomething")
   def get(self):
      """getsomething"""
      ....
```

Then it will add description and summary.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a swagger.yml.

```
summary: <your description here>
```

[Basic Structure](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/basic-structure/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not clear, can I add it like the description of field, like a decorator? For example, I use @api.doc.